# Проблемы с @babel/polyfill

Tags: webpack, сборка, babel

1) https://prnt.sc/sdausf

2) https://prnt.sc/sdav2p

3) https://prnt.sc/sdavbe

4) https://prnt.sc/sdavk7

Ребят, нет сил, как это исправить

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, ошибка была в том что не поставил точку

extensions : ['.js'], перед JS